# Replacing a found word within the string to case (in)sensitive (search and highlight)

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have taken a someone else's highlighter code and I'm trying to mod it to make it work for my project. Overall the code works fine, but there's a minor issue with displaying results. The highlighter finds the specified word and replaces the whole text within the element to specified keyword.

So in this case if I want to highlight a word "cat" from the sentence: "Cat is an awesome pet" the result that I get is "cat is an awesome pet". It would be easy to always use uppercase, but the problem with that is that needed word can be in different places within the sentence. In example: I love my cat.

What I want to do is for the script to remember the previous case-sensitivity status and after it's highlighted I want it to show previously specified uppercase or lowercase.

I have Search a keyword within the table function, after keyword is found it should highlight it.

```
// highlighter func
    function highlight_words(word, element) {
        if(word){
            var textNodes;
            word = word.replace(/\W/g, '');
            var str = word.split(" ");

            $(str).each(function(){
                var term = this;
                var textNodes = $(element).contents().filter(function(){ return this.nodeType === 3 });

                textNodes.each(function() {
                    var content = $(this).text();
                    var regex = new RegExp(term, "gi");

                    content = content.replace(regex, '<span class="highlight">' + term + '</span>');
                    $(this).replaceWith(content);
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

How I trigger the function

```
//search_inp is the keyword entered in the text input field such as "Cat"
highlight_words(search_inp, $("#FoundElem table tbody .perm-name a"));
```

What displays

```
<div id="FoundElem">
<table cellspacing="1" class="perm-table" id="table0000">
<tbody><tr class="row4" id="temp0">
    <td class="perm-name"><a title=""><span class="highlight">cat</span> is an awesome pet</a></td>
</tr></tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I was able to get this to work is by adding CSS capitalization to all the keywords. It works for my case, but for the case where you want to keep previous value, it wouldn't work.

Anyways, here's a css that ended up helping me.

```
.highlight {
    background-color:yellow;
    text-transform:capitalize;
}
```